# Tableau published data source

Tags: tableau-api

Need help with tableau .tdsx usage.

Current Process: -
We publish and refresh data sources (packaged .tdsx) to the tableau server. 
Our customers download the data sources and build ad hoc reports for their business needs.

Problem: -
If the customer already build some views last month, is there a way to download the latest ‘.tdsx’ file and use it in the existing workbook were they created the views.
Today, customer is re-creating the views using each month updated ‘.tdsx’ files.

Can you suggest a better way to achieve this? I can provide more details if it is needed.

Note: - Publishing a packaged workbook (.twbx) with views in it is not feasible as the report requirement varies most of the months.

Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having your customer connect directly to the published data source from Tableau Desktop -- i.e. connect to the data source on the Tableau Server. That way they automatically see the data changes when they next refresh when you publish an updated copy of the data source.

There are some pros/cons with working with published data sources. The biggest con is that if you are changing the data source itself dramatically - e.g. revising calculated fields, aliases etc, - you may need to first download a copy, edit that, and then republish if you want others to see your changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving 'new' datasource as another .tdsx file locally, just add it as a new datasource to existing workbook and then right-click 'old' datasource in Data pane and choose 'Replace'.